# How can I stow my webcam behind my monitor?

Tags: technology, furniture

This is my monitor with my webcam mounted:

[image]

Typical setup, nothing special. Now, I dislike keeping my webcam on top of my monitor - even if I cover it. It's distracting. So - I want to "stow it away" behind it. The problem is that the thing falls off the monitor stand.

Now, I could install an adhesive-mounted or screw-mounted small shelf; but that would get in the way when I move the monitor itself. I was wondering how to otherwise create a sort of a "rest", or shelf, or other contraption which would hold my webcam: Behind my monitor, but no lower than the connection of the monitor body to its arm.

Notes:

- The camera's "arm" or base is foldable both further inwards and further outwards, in case that helps.
- The farther, bottom part of the Camera's mounting arm has a rifled hole for screwing in a tripod base.

Comment: Does the camera have a mounting point for a tripod, or any hole in the base? You could maybe attach a cheap tripod mount.

Comment: @StuartF: It does, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

As an owner of a 3D printer, my first thought is to print a caddy, but that sort of solution isn't for everyone. On the other hand, if you have a conveniently shaped container that you can fasten to the back of the monitor with double sided foam tape, you'd have the equivalent caddy.

Even shaped cardstock or cardboard would be attached to the back in a shape appropriate for receiving the camera's folding arm. It appears from the image that one can straighten the arm to be perpendicular to the camera body. If the caddy was open bottomed and shaped in a box or spread-leg box manner, the straight arm would slide inside, while the camera body would prevent it from falling through.

Top view of two options below:

[image: camera box sketch]

Alternatively, a drink mix box could be cut to substitute for the cardboard version:

[image: camera box photo]

Comment: I understand you're suggesting shaping something so that the arm will slide into it. But - I don't quite follow your first diagram. I don't suppose I could ask you to doodle something in perspective?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add "top view" to the drawing of the two different options. Consider that the drink box would have a square cross section rather than an oval, for the left hand diagram. The right hand diagram uses the monitor back wall as the box wall, minimal difference between the two, really.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe put (stick) a small cardboard tray on top of the monitor support.

[image]

When you don't want the camera on top, lift it off the monitor and put it on the tray.

(Find or make the tray by cutting-down an appropriate box.)

Good luck.

Comment: How did you draw that annotation on the pic?

Comment: @AlexS Hi. I bet if you asked that as a question, you'd get a few different answers. I imported a copy from the page into Illustrator, sketched the shape on an overlay, and dropped the result into my answer. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If the camera is not heavy, you can cut out a shape from foam packing material , put a hard plastic pipe through it.[image]